# Regex to get every character that appears between equals sign and text

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to get all the text/numbers that appear after the equals sign such that this input

```
"Input: m = 2, n = 3, indices = [[0,1],[1,1]]"
```

Would return this output:

```
[2,3, [[0,1],[1,1]] ]
```

This is what I have tried:

```
eachEx.match(/= (.+)/)[1]
```

However this returns:

```
2, n = 3, indices = [[0,1],[1,1]]
```

I have thought of splitting the string and iterating through each element, passing it through the match I have. However, the problem is that I would lose the ability to know whether or not the element in question was meant to be a string or an integer or an array. I need to know this information

Comment: The problem is that a regex could parse regular languages: numbers, strings and one-level-depth arrays... but if you want arrays of undefined depth, then you need to make your own parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't be surprised if you end up needing to write a simple parser for this, rather than a single regex. But the specific example given *can* be done with a single regex. It's just that I suspect when you throw more examples at it, it'll become too complicated.

**If** the thing that makes the `,` a delimiter after the `2` and `3` but not in the final match is that the final match is wrapped in `[___]`, then you can use an alternation to adjust what characters are allowed in the capture:

```
/= (\[[^=]+\]|[^=,]+)/
```

That says that if the text starts with `[` and ends with `]`, match all non-`=` inside it. Otherwise, match all non-`=` and non-`,`.

Then, to get all the matches, add a `g` flag and use `matchAll`, then post-process the iterable you get from it to extract the capture groups:

```js
const eachEx = "Input: m = 2, n = 3, indices = [[0,1],[1,1]]";

const match = eachEx.matchAll(/= (\[[^=]+\]|[^=,]+)/g);
console.log(Array.from(match, ([, capture]) => capture));
```

As an example of a string that would be parsed incorrectly by that, consider `"a = [3, [2, ], b = 3"`, which gives us the array `[ "[3, [2, ]", "3" ]` when probably it should be an error:

```js
const eachEx = "Input: a = [3, [2, ], b = 3";

const match = eachEx.matchAll(/= (\[[^=]+\]|[^=,]+)/g);
console.log(Array.from(match, ([, capture]) => capture));
```

Hence the warning above that you may need to write a simple parser instead.

Comment: I'm looking for everything that appears between an equal sign and some text or the end of the string. So `[2, 3, [[0,1] ,[1,1]] ]`

Comment: @Emm - So you're looking for an *array* of all the matches.

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: @Emm - What tells the regular expression that the `,` after `2` and `3` is a delimiter, but the `,` in the last match isn't? The fact it's in `[]`?

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense

Comment: @Emm - I've updated the answer. But don't be surprised if when you start throwing real data at it, you end up needing to write a simple parser that tracks opening and closing `[]`, rather than a single regex.

Comment: I think that you should add to the answer a simple warning that this regex will also parse ill formed strings and arrays, like `a = [3, [2, ], b = 3`. OP is trying to parse a non regular language, so it's impossible to build a regex that parses it correctly without also parsing wrong constructs.

Comment: @Miguel - I think my first paragraph does the warning. But I like the idea of an example, thanks. I've added it.